# How can I access device information without using packages in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-android

How can I access device information without using packages in Flutter? How can I get the information of the device where the app is installed in my Flutter app?

Comment: what kind info you want to get?

Comment: Device İnformation; device type(android,ios) and another information

Comment: What do you mean "without using packages"? You could write your own platform-specific code then use [platform channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels). But why would you do that?

Comment: Why you want to reinvent the whole wheel and then fight with the issues that you created yourself. Better use a flutter package that is why flutter is there.

Comment: Why not use packages? Most if not all packages are open source anyway, so if it's a hard requirement to not use packages, simply find a package that can do it and copy their code

Comment: This is an assignment given to me to get the job. I think they want to test my use of method channel and they gave me this task.

Comment: What do you expect us to do? Complete your assignment?

Comment: No, I just wanted to know how it's done. It says so in the title. If I wanted you to do it, I would have written it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'd be better off using packages. But if you really want/need to do it, you'd have to write platform-specific code code in the native language of the targeted platform (ie. Swift or Objective-C for iOS/Mac, Kotlin or Java for Android, etc), then use so-called [platform channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to pass messages between your app and the platform-specific code.

If you'd like to get details about the device, on iOS you'd use [`UIDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDevice), on Android you'd typically want [`Build`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build).

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done through Method Channel

Comment: Do I have to write code in natural language for android and ios?

Comment: i think you mean native language? Why you want to reinvent the whole wheel and then fight with the issues that you created yourself. Better use a flutter package that is why flutter is there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @VolkanUstekidag  take a look at this: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels